Textfield Visualtransformation crashing iwth offsetmapping originaltotransformed returned invalid mapping
I have a textfield and trying to achieve something like

When I set a value to textfield programmatically. Its a username field on login form. If it is saved previously by user then we mask first 4 characters in textfield with '*'
like "johndoe" ==> "****doe"



But when user is editing meaning if user wants to enter another username, I want to keep this transformation off and let user enter characters. No I can not add a button to hide/show it.

I am trying to do this with visual transformation but running into issues.
when I edit seems error like offsetmapping.originaltotransformed returned invalid mapping:
Anyone knows how can I achieve this ?
class UserNameMaskTransformation() : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return maskFilter(text)
    }
}


fun maskFilter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
    var maskLen = 4
    var maskChar = "*"

    val maskingChars = AnnotatedString(maskChar.repeat(maskLen))

    val subString = AnnotatedString(text.substring(4))
    return TransformedText(maskingChars + subString, OffsetMapping.Identity)
    
}


Can you clarify what you mean by 'when I set a value to textfield'? Do you mean setting it programmatically? Also, if the user can see the hidden characters while editing, what’s the purpose of hiding them in the first place? Your requirements are a bit unclear. Please add more details to your question. Or you can add a button to hide unhide the chars

Updated question with more details


You can use the onFocusChanged callback to determine the current focus and apply the relevant transformation.
@Composable
fun TextFieldMaskTest() {
    var hasFocus by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("johndoe") }
    Column {
        TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                        .onFocusChanged { hasFocus = it.isFocused },
                value = text,
                onValueChange = {
                    text = it
                },
                visualTransformation = if (hasFocus) {
                    VisualTransformation.None
                } else {
                    MaskingTransformation()
                }
        )
        TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
    }
}

Update your transformation class to handle the text length properly (as suggested by the @Abdo21)
class MaskingTransformation : VisualTransformation {
    private val maskLen = 4
    private val maskChar = "*"
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val maskLengthToUse = minOf(maskLen, text.text.length)
        return TransformedText(
                AnnotatedString(maskChar.repeat(maskLengthToUse) + text.text.substring(maskLengthToUse)),
                OffsetMapping.Identity
        )
    }
}


This is little different than my initial requirement but it works for me.

You have a problem in the implementation of the maskFilter method! Let's say that if the text is empty or less than 4 characters, it will crash the app in this line text.substring(4) because the 4th index does not exist if the text is empty or less than 4 characters.
The answer is to take the minimum between the text length and the number 4. In this way, we will use the text length as the number of characters to mask if the text length is less than 4, otherwise we will use the number 4 you provide.
Here is the updated code:
fun maskFilter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
    var maskLen = 4
    var maskChar = "*"

    val m = min(maskLen, text.length)

    val maskingChars = AnnotatedString(maskChar.repeat(m))

    val subString = AnnotatedString(text.substring(m))
    return TransformedText(maskingChars + subString, OffsetMapping.Identity)
}

